# Live data processing and reporting (advice)

Tags: sql

## TLDR;

Ok, so what I've written below isn't very clear...

Long story short. I am looking for a database solution, which supports high speed ingestion, fast processing and the ability to perform large and complex queries, either directly via an API (for client side reporting) or via a client, which can be accessed via an API.

Whilst I've had a look at various solutions, I'm not experienced enough (in this field) to know which is best, and whether their implementation is suitable to my requirements (hence the attempt of explaining my requirements.)

We currently utilise a lot of AWS services, so anything hosted directly, or via an AMI could be useful.

---

I've been given the task of redesigning and upgrading our current data analytics system which essentially runs on extremely old and unsupported software, is rather slow and completely unscalable.

## Background

Currently, we have a ColdFusion server that listens to files being received via Email, FTP and via manual upload via our client interface. Files are then parsed and ingested into a fact table.

Jobs are then added to a queue in which tells our data processor to collect fact records over 30 minute intervals and run some calculations on them.

Due to the age of ColdFusion, it's been decided we're getting rid of it and finding something a little more IoT/Big Data aware.

## What I've tried

#### Data restructure/normalisation

So, a lot of the functionality was based upon requirements defined by customers/users over 10 years ago and these are no longer relevant. With this in mind, the data was restructured to make it a little more easier to understand and index.

#### Fact/summary tables

As intervals between each data record could be completely random, i.e. 1-30 minutes, the system has to cope with all, whilst providing a consistent experience. This is why our current system defaults to reporting in 30 minute intervals.

The fact table contains raw data, i.e. `id, timestamp, value`, indexed on the ID and Timestamp accordingly.

I then looked at using Window functions to generate rows for each minute between record, dividing the difference between records by the number of minutes and filling the gap.

This obviously caused at minimum 48 rows in the summary table, to become 1440 rows, which slows things down even further.

Another solution tried, was then to use the window functions as above, but at the point of querying the data for reporting - this failed straight away.

#### ElasticCache/Solr

After processing the data, I thought about indexing it using ElasticCache or similar and initial tests looked good, however their aggregation functionality was not suitable for what I needed (i.e. you could group by date etc, however you'd lose the ability to paginate.)

## Now what...

So, I've been looking at various in-memory solutions, i.e. Hadoop/Hive, which on the face of things look amazing, I'm concerned about how I'd make the data available to the front-end.

I presume this would need an API to communicate with Hadoop/Hive?

I appreciate it's a bit of a open question but I'm limited by my employer who won't cough up for someone unless I can prove I've exhausted all avenues.

Comment: Voted to close. None of this makes any sense.

Comment: Are you asking for help on how to improve your SQL query? Or for help on how to design your data ware house? Or something entirely different?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - Rather than straight out "voting to close" could you suggest what I could do to improve my question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Sorry, I've spent some time trying to work out how to ask for a little help on SO, it appears that my question caused more confusion than asked questions. 

DuduMarkovitz - I'll update my question to make it a little easier for people to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a bit vague. Therefore let me try to propose one option and I'd be happy to dive deeper if you like by updating my answer.

Since you mentioned that you're currently already using a lot of AWS services, have you considered using AWS IoT Analytics for processing, storing and analyzing your IoT data? It comes with a scalable ingestion part, datastores optimized for IoT use cases and integrates with AWS machine learning suites and QuickSight for analysis.

Have a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/iot-analytics

Disclaimer: I'm working at AWS, but this post is solely based on my personal opinion and is not an official AWS statement.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Will update it, thanks for reminding.